# Comoving distance units in astrophysics

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, units, galaxies

I'm solving a problem and I'm struggling in a conceptual step where I need to work with some magnitudes, but I don't understand what they express at all.

All of them are distances, for example in one case is given the comoving distance to a galaxy or projected radius of a galaxy and the unities are,

$h^{-1}Mpc$, or similar

Why in this cases distances are expressed as length per unit time? I'm not an expert and maybe the reason is obvious, but I could not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this notation, you might think $h$ is the Hubble constant $H_{0}$ but it is actually a dimensionless constant.

$H_{0} = 100~\mathrm{h~km~s^{-1}~Mpc^{-1}}$

So indeed the distances are in Mpc, or Megaparsecs.

This arose because we did not know the exact value of Hubble's constant: debates used to be between 50-100 and now debates are between 67-73 (ish).